# passport yahoo authentication fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, yahoo

I get after I enter my credentials when yahoo asks for it

> InternalOpenIDError: Failed to verify assertion
>           at C:\Users\jack\Desktop\practice\stackPrac\jsPrac\combineAuth\node_modules\passport-openid\lib\passport-openid\strategy.js:184:36
>           at C:\Users\jack\Desktop\practice\stackPrac\jsPrac\combineAuth\node_modules\openid\openid.js:1068:12
>           at C:\Users\jack\Desktop\practice\stackPrac\jsPrac\combineAuth\node_modules\openid\openid.js:1150:16
>           at C:\Users\jack\Desktop\practice\stackPrac\jsPrac\combineAuth\node_modules\openid\openid.js:664:13

I will show you code I use

```
passport.use(new YahooStrategy({
    returnURL : "http://localhost:3000/auth/yahoo/return",
    realm : "http://localhost:3000"
}, function(identifier, profile,done){
    profile.identifier = identifier;
    console.log("profile:", profile);
    return done(null, profile);
}))

app.get("/auth/yahoo",
    passport.authenticate("yahoo", {failureRedirect : "/login"}),
    function(req, res){
        res.redirect("/")
    }
);

app.get("/auth/yahoo/return",
    passport.authenticate("yahoo", {failureRedirect : "/login"}),
    function(req, res){
        res.redirect("/")
    }
)
```

I use `const YahooStrategy = require("passport-yahoo").Strategy;`

I really wanted to use yahoo for logging it but it doesn't seem it is well supported. searching around online shows that the API system is not good like Facebook.

Anybody see see something wrong in the code?

I tried following the passport [example](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-yahoo/blob/master/examples/signon/app.js)

I tried creating [app](https://developer.yahoo.com/apps/create/) with yahoo for Oauth but it seemed buggy.

Comment: Hi, Do you find any solution regarding this, as I am also facing the same issue. Please help. Thanks in advance